# How to persist JsessionID in wso2 identity server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Currently we are using wso2 IS  4.1.0 version, entitlements service for policy decisions. As entitlement service is a secured service we authenticate and get the cookie then pass the cookie along with the entitlements service requests. we are using jsessionid cookie and ran into a situation where if the wso2 is goes down we have to restart our app as it has a stale cookie we refresh the cookie on a time interval every 15 min. Is there a way in wso2 is to persist the cookie if it get restarted. we tried commenting the     inside wso2is-4.1.0\repository\conf\tomcat\carbon\META-INF.
Can you suggest on how we can configure for persistence of jsessionid cookies in wso2is

Thanks
Kishore

Answer (score 0):

User session (jsessionid) is not persisted in server side. So you can re-authenticated after 15min and get a new jsessionid. (If you received an authenticate failure, you can re authenticated). you need to implement PEP in such way.

If you are using basic authentication to authenticate with entitlement service. You can send both cookie (jsessionid) and basic auth header...  if cookie is valid it would be authenticate with cookie, if not use basic auth headers and returns the new cookie to client. you can find some java code for this here.. but this is not for entitlement service but you can use....

[1] https://github.com/soasecurity/soasecurity/blob/master/user-mgt/client/remote-user-400/src/main/java/org/soa/security/sample/user/mgt/SampleUserRoleMgtClient.java

Comment: Please check this java code also.. here it is trying to re-authenticated, if authentication error... https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/xacml-samples/pep/SamplePEP/

Comment: We would like to know whether there is a way to persist the JsessionId because we already take care of getting new cookie every 15 min but between the 1 min and 15 min if the wso2 server goes down the cookie we hold is a inactive cookie as the wso2 identity server is not persisting the cookie even the actual validity of the cookie is 15 min.

Comment: We would like to know whether there is a way to persist the JsessionId because we already take care of getting new cookie every 15 min but between the 1 min and 15 min if the wso2 server goes down the cookie we hold is a inactive cookie as the wso2 identity server is not persisting the cookie even the actual validity of the cookie is 15 min. I have read that in tomcat container we can persist the JSessionID incase of restarting event of the container

Comment: This is not supporting by default. But WSO2 product are using the tomcat.  therefore, if you can persist tomcat session. then it would works... please check this... http://kishanthan.wordpress.com/2013/02/05/session-replication-of-applications-in-wso2-application-server/